# $ is not a function - nested functions

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I try to execute script first on `(document).ready` on WordPress website, but I want it to also work after cart update AJAX is triggered. I receive

> $ is not a function error

when I try to pass "$", so that I can use it instead of "jQuery". How can I use it within function QtyChng without errors?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    QtyChng($);
});

jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function($){
    QtyChng($);
});

function QtyChng($) {    
    $('.woocommerce form.cart, .woocommerce td.product-quantity').on( 'click', '.test-button', function($) {        
        alert("test");   
    });
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `$`, you're not passing anything sensible to it.

Comment: Did you use `jQuery.noConflict();`?

Comment: I don't use `jQuery.noConflict();` So far I've always used `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ });` and then could type `$` within square brackets. I would not like to remove `$` and type jQuery instead, that's the whole point of my question to make it work with `$`. So far I have `alert("test"); `, but I plan to add lines with `$` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just have to make the switch from `$` to `jQuery` once in the file, so you could do something like this

```
(function($){

$(document).ready(function(){
    QtyChng();
});

$( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
    QtyChng();
});

function QtyChng() {    
    $('.woocommerce form.cart, .woocommerce td.product-quantity').on( 'click', '.test-button', function() {        
        alert("test");   
    });
}

})(jQuery);
```